Default proper path for Diesel in Windows
I had problems running the Diesel command in my shell in Linux until I set up a $PATH to the executable. Now I am setting up Visual Studio Code in Windows 10 and I am having the same problem. What is the default path that I need to set for the PATH variable in Windows?
I tried to find the path using the default file browser but was not successful.

You should have C:\Users\<USER>\.cargo\bin in your Path. That is where Cargo will install executables when running cargo install unless configured otherwise.
